# things that mess up your environment variables -the ultimate .htaccess

Tags: git, .htaccess

I work have a project on github and I clone my repo into 3 different places:

1. localhost
2. example.com
3. test.example.com

I need to decide what repo I am in, in order to set a correct environment variable that will be used to set error reporting, db settings and such. I like to do that by checking the value of $_SERVER['HOST']. I expect the value to be only one of the 3 above. This is not the case due to the fact that you can access the sites in more ways than the above.

Having search the net for tons of .htaccess files that can be the same on all 3 environments above, I still haven't found one that works.

The following URLs need to be redirected:

```
www.example.com -> example.com
www.test.example.com -> test.example.com
example.com/test -> test.example.com
www.example.com/test -> test.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.example.com [R=301,L]
```